# vimsearch for repeated string in a line

Tags: search, vim

I'm trying to search for lines where any string is repeated twice on the same line. I am able to search it with a script to read through the file but I am unable to search manually while reviewing in vim/gvim

Example:

```
1 connect ABC ABC
2 connect X YZ
3 connect 123 123
```

Here I need to highlight lines 1 and 3 since same pattern is repeated after the keyword `connect`.

Something similar to `connect \([^ \t]\+\) \1` where `\1` would replace the string read in the first register.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, [your pattern works as-is](https://i.imgur.com/35tnnB2.png). Do you want more? A way to act on the two matching lines? Something else.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I had the right answer but wasn't executing it correctly. This does work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the right command but was incorrectly executed, so I'll re-write the answer here just in case someone else has a similar issue.

```
connect \([^ \t]\+\) \1
```

where \1 would replace the string read in the first register